# Fade in a box text overlay with a hoverable dropdown

Tags: html, css, blogger

I'm a blogger and I'm trying my best to learn to code certain things for everyday use. Today I'm trying to get a picture in which when you hover over it it fades in with a text over it and I want that text to have a drop down menu.

Ex: I have a picture of books. When hovered over the word Books appears in the middle of the picture and the photo has a transparent overlay. When you hover over the word Books a drop down menu says Hauls, Reviews, and Inspired By. I would also like to be able to just click the word Books and have it take me to all post labeled books.

Here is the code I have so far:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.container:hover .image {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.container:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <img src="https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4397/35532470254_614bf14a8b_b.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">

  <div class="middle">
    <div class="text"><a href="http://www.mynerdydelights.com/search/label/books">Books</a></div>

  </div>

</div>

<div class="dropdown">

  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>

  <div class="dropdown-content">

    <a href="#">Hauls</a>

    <a href="#">Reviews</a>

    <a href="#">Inspired By</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

I hope this makes sense! Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: You trying to create when image hovered the books word showing in the middle of image and if books word hovered the dropdown text showing. Its you mean?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean

Comment: You want done with pure css or some javascript?

Comment: Pure css please

Answer (score 0):

First, move the `dropdown-content` inside `middle` content, because CSS hover can't access if it's not the parent element, you can change HTML markup like this.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: .5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.container:hover .image {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.container:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  background-color: #000000;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}


/* this for show dropdown */

.middle .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

.middle:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4397/35532470254_614bf14a8b_b.jpg" class="image" alt="" />
  <div class="middle">
    <a href="http://www.mynerdydelights.com/search/label/books" class="text">Books</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Hauls</a>
      <a href="#">Reviews</a>
      <a href="#">Inspired By</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think it works like you want.. Dropdown content always shows if middle hovered.